# I have two inner class in class and i can't init class in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I can't init inner class. IDE me returning error, namely "'self' used before all stored properties are initialized". I attach picture where look error is ok
[image]

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54604926/edit) your question to include the relevant code *as text* - An image cannot be copied to an answer and is also not friendly for search engines.  On a point of style, Swift properties and variables should start with a lower case letter and use camel case, so `auth`, `session` and `userID`, not `AUTH`, `SESSION` and `USER_ID`

Comment: self is not init yet. You can't use it till all stored property initialised

Comment: And you are creating STRONG REF CYCLE make weak one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is correct, you are attempting to pass `self` to the constructor of `Customer` before all stored properties are initialised, as `SESSION` won't be initialised until after the `Session` object is initialised, but that needs `self` - your two requirements are mutually exclusive.

You may need to rethink your architecture; If nothing else, the reference from `Customer` to `Session` combined with the reference from `Session` to `Customer` will give you a retain cycle and a memory leak.

If you want to use the current architecture, it is probably best to make the `Customer` property of `Session` a weak optional to avoid both your initialisation problem and the retain cycle;

```
class Customer {
    let session: Session
    let auth: Auth

    init() {
        self.auth = Auth()
        self.session = Session()
        session.customer = self
    }

    class Session {
        weak var customer: Customer?
    }
}
```

You *could* make `customer` an implicitly unwrapped optional to avoid the need to unwrap it explicitly each time you refer to it, but you risk a crash if `customer` is released or not set:

```
class Session {
    weak var customer: Customer!
 }
```

On a point of style, Swift properties and variables should start with a lower case letter and use camel case, so `auth`, `session` and `userID`, not `AUTH`, `SESSION` and `USER_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create recursive structured classes.

- An inner class is required to initialize the outer class.
- An outer class is required to initialize the inner class.

```swift
class OuterClass {
    class InnerClass {
        let outerClass: OuterClass
        init(outerClass: OuterClass) {
            self.outerClass = outerClass
        }
    }

    let innerClass: InnerClass

    init() {
        self.innerClass = InnerClass(outerClass: self)
    }
}
```